# systemd always load old service setting

Tags: systemd

I have a strange question on Ubuntu Server 20.04, which is upgraded from 19.10.

I have a service defined while 19.10 in systemd/system. It works without any problem in that version.

Now, I need to change some setting in the service file. So I edit the file, use daemon-reload to reload it and try to use the new one, but systemd keep to use the old one. I know it is using the old one because the 2 versions point to different binary which I can see from status displaying.

Every time I start the service, systemctl warns me to use daemon-reload to reload the changed file. Use daemon-reload, even reboot won't fix.

I tried to remove the service file and reload it. It says service is not found while trying starting, which is good. But when I put the changed file back, it still use the old one while nothing is wrong with the service file.

I wonder maybe there is another place than /etc/systemd/system to save all settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

The problem found it at the [unit] of the service file, one line says:
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/<old.service.file>

After remove that line and reload, the problem is fixed.

It's still strange that the service file and the requested one in init.d are cached some where in systemd.

I leave this question here for who encounter the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation, I made a syntax mistake in one of my unit files, and `sudo service <servicename> status` was showing the error, I fixed the error in the unit file. I didn't have any `SourcePath` lines.

I did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` but the same old error was shown. Also tried `sudo systemctl daemon-reexec` with no effect. Ended up restarting the system and the new file was reloaded. Turns out that restarting the system was faster than trying to figure out why systemd was loading the old version of the file.